# qpython with sl4a library

Tags: sl4a, qpython

I've been googling around and found people showing scripts importing sl4a instead of androidhelper. When I try to do it I receive 'no module named sl4a'. Does it run only in Qpython3? I have sl4a for arm in qpython's site-packages folder. Tks.

Answer (score 2):

In qpython2, sl4a module is package inside androidhelper. In fact, sl4a module will get imported inside androidhelper

You can do either below to import sl4a alone in qpython2

```
from androidhelper import sl4a
# OR
import androidhelper.sl4a as sl4a
# OR
import androidhelper # then access sl4a with androidhelper.sl4a
```

In qpython3, both sl4a and androidhelper module is within the sys.path so you can just import any of them

Comment: You may upvote or accept the answer to promote them to others :p

Comment: I tried to find an API to get Receiver Signal strength for a LTE connection but with no success. Is this API inside sl4a and not androidhelper alone? Could you help me find this information? Tks.